# Why don't commands work from xargs that work from bash?

Tags: xargs

The -t option to xargs makes it display the command it is about to run.  The command fails when xargs runs it, but when I copy and paste it to the prompt it works fine.

```
# echo alpine/3.10 alpine-3-10 | xargs -ti /var/lib/snapd/snap/bin/lxc launch images:{}
/var/lib/snapd/snap/bin/lxc launch images:alpine/3.10 alpine-3-10
Creating the instance
Error: Failed instance creation: The requested image couldn't be found
# /var/lib/snapd/snap/bin/lxc launch images:alpine/3.10 alpine-3-10
Creating alpine-3-10
<works correctly>
```

Comment: Compare `var='a b'; mkdir $var` and `var='a b'; mkdir "$var"`. `xargs ... {} ...` is like the second but you want the first

Comment: Yup, testing indicates that is indeed the problem.  If you make that an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @Pascal Did the comments or my answer solve your issue? If the answer helped, you can say thanks by up voting and/or checking as answered.

Answer (score 0):

You have a list of images that are separated by spaces. You wish to run each of them through a lxc launch.

```
echo alpine/3.10 alpine-3-10 | tr ' ' '\n' | \
    xargs -ti /var/lib/snapd/snap/bin/lxc launch images:{}
```

This takes your list of image names separated by spaces. The `tr` command changes spaces in those names to '\n' (newlines). Then the lines are passed to xargs. The default this way is to run only one line per execution.

I test this by using `echo /var/lib/snapd/snap/bin/lxc` and here are the results:

```
echo /var/lib/snapd/snap/bin/lxc launch images:alpine/3.10
/var/lib/snapd/snap/bin/lxc launch images:alpine/3.10
echo /var/lib/snapd/snap/bin/lxc launch images:alpine-3-10
/var/lib/snapd/snap/bin/lxc launch images:alpine-3-10
```